# php how to loop z to a?

Tags: php

i was read this document [document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

they can loop from A to Z with this code.

```
$string = 'A';
for ( $i = 0; $i<=1; $i++ ) {
    echo $string;
    ++$string;
}
```

and result can go from A to B or more than this up to $i

**but!!**

i can't do loop from Z to A with this code

```
--$string;
```

Does anyone know how to loop from Z to A?

ps1. i can't use range(); because 'Z' is in variable.

ps2. this is excel column that can go from A to Z, AA, AB or more then this.. so, i can't use variable in range or number to character.

Comment: Shouldn't ++string; be ++$string;... and sadly, while the increment operator works with strings, the decrement operator doesn't; you need to decrement chars the long way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
$range = range("Z", "A");
foreach ( $range as $chr ) {
    echo $chr;
}
```

Output

```
ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

If you must start with `Z`

```
$s = 'Z';
while($s != "@"){
    print($s) and $s = chr(ord($s) - 1);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i can't use range(); because 'Z' store in variable.

Comment: @user1859385 So...? `range($var, 'A')`?

Comment: If you have `A-Z` why not just sort ... except you have other requirement and you are not just dealing with alphabets

Comment: $i = 1;
  foreach ( range( $start_col, 'A' ) as $letter ) {
   $start_col = $letter;
   if ( $i == 2 ) {
    break;
   }
   $i++;
  }

wow! this work great.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($alpha = 90; $alpha &gt;= 65; $alpha--) {
  echo chr($alpha);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Decrementing Operators don't work on chars as far as I know.

This workaround should do the trick

```
$string = 'Z';
for ( $i = 0; $i<=25; $i++ ) {
    echo $string;
    $string = chr(ord($string) - 1);
}
```